# How do I export to cinema 4d?

Tags: rendering, texturing, export

I have a render that looks great in Blender, but when transfered using any method it looks terrible in Cinema 4D. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

All I need is my textures to somewhat resemble what I have in blender. I can include for info if needed.

Comment: Are you using raster (png, jpg,...) textures or procedural textures using the shader editor ? Hint : You can't export procedural textures

Comment: i purchased a gig off of fiverr and he modeled it for me in blender... some are png textures but most are most are internal textures (basic colors). is there a way i can bake textures for my object so i can link them up in c4d? theres a lot... 97 i think.

Comment: C4D (even Cycles4D) and Blender have very different shading workflows... I don't remember offhand how C4D supports gltf, but otherwise you will have to reproduce any blender procedural materials with C4D materials.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: In order to have your materials in C4D, you need to create a UV map for your objects and bake your materials to get Texture images (Normal maps, color map, specular maps, AO Maps, and so) and then you just need to adjust the parameters inside C4D